# Azure Container Apps and terraform issue

Tags: azure, terraform

Im creating a number of azure resources and infrastructures and thus far the only one that asks for a username/password is  azurerm_container_app.  I've been able to build all other resources fine (VMs, databases, vnets, etc) with the 'Contributor' role that i have.
azurerm_container_app however fails with:

> invalid registry config for Container App...must supply either
> identity or username/password_secret_name

Here is the code:

```
resource "azurerm_container_app" "aca" {
  name = "${var.name_prefix}-aca"

  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.app_env.id
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  revision_mode                = "Single"

  registry {
    server               = "cregistry101010.azurecr.io"
 #username             = ""
 #password_secret_name = ""
  }

 # secret {
 #   name  = "docker-io-pass"
 #   value = "MyDockerIOPass"
 # }

  ingress {
    allow_insecure_connections = false
    external_enabled           = true
    target_port                = 5050
    traffic_weight {
      percentage = 100
    }
  }

  template {
    container {
      name   = "app-data-svc"
      image  = "data-svc:latest"
      cpu    = 0.25
      memory = "0.5Gi"
    }
  }
  tags = var.tags
}
```

As you can see i have the username and password commented out above because i am not sure what they are suppose to be.  Are they my AD login? or is this something i need to set up?  Again, thus far i have been able to do everything by doing an az login before running the terraform apply and as mentioned i have the contributor role.

Thanks much

Comment: Do you use ACR or docker hub? If you use ACR you can use identity to provide pull permission. But if you use docker hub you need to use username/password to pull your images.

Comment: i use ACR.  i ended up creating a azurerm_user_assigned_identity and azurerm_role_assignment, then for the registry node of azurerm_container_app i have ```identity = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai.id```.   Still same issue - i think my issue may be that i have just the Contributor role - tried creating this manually in the portal and it still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As you can see i have the username and password commented out above because i am not sure what they are supposed to be. Are they my AD login?

Thanks to `Krzysztof Madej` for suggesting the same.

If you use `azure container registry` you can use  `user_assigned_identity` to pull image from `ACR`.

For pulling container registry with  `AD login` is won't work, it requires container registry with `acrpull` access with identity method not with directly username and password of `AD login`.

Here is the updated code to create a `container app` with a `private registry` with `Identity` using terraform.

I have already created a `container registry` with an `image` and used the same image in the `container app`

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "Resource-Group"
}

data "azurerm_container_registry" "acr" {
  name                = "containerrig1"
  resource_group_name = "rg-name"
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "containerapp" {
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  name                = "containerappmi"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "containerapp" {
  scope                = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
  role_definition_name = "acrpull"
  principal_id         = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.containerapp.principal_id
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_user_assigned_identity.containerapp
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_container_app" "containerapp" {
  name                         = "${var.aca_name}app"
  container_app_environment_id = azurerm_container_app_environment.containerappenv.id
  resource_group_name          = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  revision_mode                = "Multiple"
 
  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.containerapp.id]
  }
 
  registry {
    server   = data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server
    identity = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.containerapp.id
  }
 

  template {
    container {
      name   = "firstcontainerappacracr"
      image  = "${data.azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/samples/nginx"
      cpu    = 0.25
      memory = "0.5Gi"
 
      readiness_probe {
        transport = "HTTP"
        port      = 80
      }
 
      liveness_probe {
        transport = "HTTP"
        port      = 80
      }
 
      startup_probe {
        transport = "HTTP"
        port      = 80
      }
    }
  }
 
}
```

**Terraform apply:**

[image]

Comment: i did end up coming across and article suggesting this approach and tried it.  still same error.  As mentioned to Krzysztof Madej, im beginning to to think it is a role related issue with my account. i have the Contributor role.  Strangely thus far i have had no issues creating resources (vms, dbs, container registry, storage)...just container apps are killing me

Comment: If you are trying to pull an image from a private registry, it requires private registry access with the Identity method in Terraform. However, even if you have the Contributor role on your Azure AD account, it won't work, whereas you can create other resources in your subscription without any issues like VM, Storage.

Comment: how do you solve this then developers that have only the contributor role?

Comment: The Contributor role in Azure grants users the ability to manage and create Azure resources but doesn't provide permissions to pull images from a private container registry, If you want to create a container apps with private registry using Contributor, upload same image to any public Repositories and use the same image without any credentials but if you are using Private registry its not possible.

Comment: According to this document, Contributors should be able to push/pull to registries :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles

Comment: Contributors role is enough but when you are trying to pull images from private registry using Terraform, it requires access to identity not to Azure AD user.

Comment: ive accepted. @VenkatV - wonder if you add your comment about Contributors as that was the role i was inquiring about specifically - and may be helpful to others as well without have to read through the comments